# $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ is noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

This follows from Hilbert's basis theorem, which is valid for polynomial rings over any noetherian ring. But is there a more elementary proof, knowing that $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID (even a Euclidean domain)?

Comment: Hilbert's Basis Theorem is elementary, the proof only takes about 5 lines and is self-contained.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Probably, elementary is the wrong word. It's a clever proof, though, and not very constructive, and I wonder if there's a more obvious proof for rings with better structure

Comment: Wait two years, then you will find the proof very constructive, obvious and wonder why you haven't found it for yourself ;).

Comment: There are very constructive proofs of the theorem.

Answer (score 3):

Using the information you have about the ideals of $\mathbb Z$ and of polynomial rings in one variable over fields (both of which are PIDs), you can —with some work— describe all ideals of the ring, and then check the ACC by hand.

Comment: I have never heard of a classification of ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. Can you state it?

Comment: Thanks Mariano - could you also mention (of course not an exact proof) a bit more in detail how you get these generators?

Comment: Ok I've asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/300170/ideals-of-mathbbzx